# like pluma or gedit with spell-check

Tags: text-editor

I am a lousy speller. I like using pluma, and gedit because they open fast, and do just about everything I need. but automatic spell-check would be very nice. I can copy paste into online spell-checkers, but this is an extra step.

I don't want to have to tell it to check spelling. I want to know what I am am spelling wrong, as I type.

the html web element "textarea" would be perfect, if it let me save, and warned me if I were about to close a not saved document.

can gedit or pluma offer this?

Comment: both pluma http://git.mate-desktop.org/pluma/tree/README and gedit have the ability to do spell checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gedit` is a text-editor [that supports plugins](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins).

One of the plugins is `Spell: Checks the spelling of the current document.` This plugin is shipped with Gedit by default, you can activate and desactivate it in the Options.

Once the plugin is activated, push **Shift+F7** to activate the spell-check, or *Tools > Spell-Check*.

You can also activate automated spell-checking in the *Tools* menu.

Comment: I see that there is a non-automatic spell-check in gedit. And that a box pops up over text i am trying to read. (LOL) I appreciate the offer, but this isn't what i want.

Comment: I don't understand. You want an automatic spell-check ? Gedit does that. You did not ask for an automatic spell-correct...

Comment: I dont want auto correct.

Comment: Oh hey, there is! the the auto correct. But i still have to click it each time I close and open gedit. But maybe there is a .conf file for gedit someplace I can edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have Pluma version 1.8.1.

A spelling plugin is available.

To make sure it is selected as a Plugin, go to:

Edit > Preferences > Plugins tab > Select "Spell Checker"

There is an option to set "Autocheck spelling" in the tools menu. It will underline misspelled words with a red wiggly line as you type.